# Failed installation of package "ncdf4" in R studio

Tags: r, installation, package, ncdf4

I'm trying to install an R package called "ncdf4".
I've tried installing it in the "packages" section in the R-studio interface, but have also tried entering `install.packages("ncdf4")` into the console.

This is the output I get in both instances:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ncdf4_1.17.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 124458 bytes (121 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 121 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ncdf4’ ...
** package ‘ncdf4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure.ac: starting
checking for nc-config... no
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error, nc-config not found or not executable.  This is a script that comes with the
netcdf library, version 4.1-beta2 or later, and must be present for configuration
to succeed.

If you installed the netcdf library (and nc-config) in a standard location, nc-config
should be found automatically.  Otherwise, you can specify the full path and name of
the nc-config script by passing the --with-nc-config=/full/path/nc-config argument
flag to the configure script.  For example:

./configure --with-nc-config=/sw/dist/netcdf4/bin/nc-config

Special note for R users:
-------------------------
To pass the configure flag to R, use something like this:

R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/joe/bin/nc-config" ncdf4

where you should replace /home/joe/bin etc. with the location where you have
installed the nc-config script that came with the netcdf 4 distribution.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ncdf4’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ncdf4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ncdf4’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXcbO2y/downloaded_packages’
```

Is anybody able to decipher what went wrong from the code that I've provided? 
Thanks.

Comment: The error message there is telling you that you need `netcdf` installed to install that R package. How to install `netcdf` on your Linux box is going to be distro specific. What are you running?

Comment: Duckmayr, I'm using a Chromebook with Crostini Linux.

Comment: tall.packages('netcdf4')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users************************/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘netcdf4’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
>  and it is the latest R 4.1.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 20.4 and ran into the same problem.

Step 1: in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Step 2: in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -y libnetcdf-dev
```

Step 3: in RStudio

```
install.packages("ncdf4")
```

After that ncdf4 was installed successfully.

Reference:
https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libnetcdf-dev

Comment: Reference are ok. But include every step required in the solution and don't depends on external urls that may not be valid or accessible in the future.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` worked for me in Step 1

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to install ncdf4.

I read a similar problem here:
https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-installing-ncdf-library-td4646986.html

I installed all the *libnetcdf* packages in the linux terminal by typing:
`sudo apt install libnetcdf-*`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu18.04 or a derived version of it, you can look for the library `netcdf4.1` by doing:

```
sudo apt-cache search libnetcdf
```

In my session (Linux Mint), I get:

```
libnetcdf-c++4 - legacy NetCDF C++ interface
libnetcdf-c++4-1 - C++ interface for scientific data access to large binary data
libnetcdf-c++4-dbg - debugging symbols for NetCDF C++
libnetcdf-c++4-dev - creation, access, and sharing of scientific data in C++
libnetcdf-c++4-doc - NetCDF C++ API documentation
libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dbg - debugging symbols for legacy NetCDF C++ interface
libnetcdf-cxx-legacy-dev - legacy NetCDF C++ interface - development files
libnetcdf-dev - creation, access, and sharing of scientific data
libnetcdf13 - Interface for scientific data access to large binary data
libnetcdff-dbg - debugging symbols for NetCDF Fortran
libnetcdff-dev - creation, access, and sharing of scientific data in Fortran
libnetcdff-doc - NetCDF Fortran documentation
libnetcdff6 - Fortran interface for scientific data access to large binary data
```

So, installing the `libnetcdf-c++4-1` should solve your issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-c++4-1
```

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux users, you probably haven't installed `netcdf`. You can use `pacman` to install `netcdf`

```
sudo pacman -S netcdf
```

Answer (score 0):

just install netcdf via apt

```
apt-get install libnetcdf-dev
```

it worked for me (ubuntu 20.04 and R 4)